# crop integer from text in python selenium web driver

Tags: python, regex

In this `Default Stock: 5` output sentence. it was stored in a variable. I want to get `5` from this string.
Code I have tried:

```
qty = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/div/ul/li")
for quanty in qty:
    quantity = quanty.text
    quantities = list(str(quantity))
    print(quantities)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this regex, if all things you are checking are in the same format "Default Stock: [number]".

```
import re
regex = r"Default Stock: (\d+)"

# code...

for q in qty:
    match = re.match(regex, q.text)
    if match:
        quantity = int(match.groups(0))
```

Comment: thanks your code helped me